# Mysql reader Clover ETL

Tags: clover, cloveretl

I am using CloverETL Designer Version: 4.0.0.030M2 for one of my projects. I want to read from a MySQL database and do some comparison and then write to the database. But I cant find a MySQL reader in the tool. Whereas a mongodb reader is present as well as a MySQL writer. Please help me on how to read from MySQL database in a clover graph. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DbInputTable (http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/dbinputtable.html) component which is generic reader for all JDBC-enabled databases. For writing to and JDBC database you can use DbOutputTable.

Writers, like MySQLDataWriter are used for fast bulk data writing using database-specific infrastructure.

Btw. best place for asking CloverETL related questions is http://forum.cloveretl.com/